# Getting a resource object's _id

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meanjs

I am creating a `Resource` object on the client side to push to the database, and I can see it has an `_id` when I `console.log` it, but when I try to set something as `resource._id` or `resource.id` it's `undefined`. Ideas?

Comment: Can u share the code

Comment: Clarified and fixed some formatting issues; consider including some more code and being a bit more specific about your problem.

Comment: I have similar probelm, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546568/how-to-loop-through-resource-returned-query-and-get-desired-value).

Comment: Thanks Hareesh, that helped me fix my problem :) and thanks AstroCB!